# int range index does not work for 0 value

Tags: marklogic

In marklogic search api, I am using int range index. However search seems to be failing for zero(0) value. Below I the sample code I am using.

```
<constraint name="Page_View_Range"> 
<range type="xs:int" facet="true"> 
  <element ns="" name="views"/> 
  <bucket name="View_Range" ' + (pageViewStart== "" ? "" : ' ge="' + pageViewStart + '" ') + (pageViewEnd== "" ? "" : ' lt="' + pageViewEnd + '" ') + '>Page_View_Range</bucket>
</range>
```

This works well when start/end index is not zero.

Answer (score 2):

This is more a JavaScript subtlety than anything else. You write `pageViewStart == ""`, but in JavaScript `0 == ""` returns true. Use the `===` operator instead..

HTH!

Comment: Maybe you should print the generated constraint to the errorlog using xdmp.log, and try if it works in QConsole